# What's the most elegant way to do this recursive many-to-many database lookup?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, recursion, recursive-query

I have a MySQL table which contains many-to-many data about users:

```
username (PK)     ip (PK)          machine_id (PK)
--------------------------------------------------
tester1           1.2.3.4          ABC
tester1           6.6.6.6          BBB
tester2           1.2.3.4          ZZZ
tester3           2.3.4.5          ABC
tester4           2.3.4.5          OOO
tester5           1.2.3.4          XYZ
tester5           8.9.7.6          BBB
tester5           1.2.3.4          OOO
tester6           9.9.9.9          ZZZ
```

It uses a combined primary key to limit the rows to unique combinations of all three columns.

As you can see, the same user can use a combination of multiple IP addresses and multiple machines to access the system. For my purposes, it's the same user if they have the same IP or Machine ID.

I want a way to find all possible connections between the data so I can identify each possible combination of username/IP/ID someone has used.

**Example**

If I wanted to find out what aliases **tester1** has used, it's easy: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%tester1%'` which would give me:

```
tester1      1.2.3.4     ABC
tester1      6.6.6.6     BBB
```

I can then connect the IPs 1.2.3.4 and 6.6.6.6 with this user, and if I look up both of those IPs I can see they have used a few other names and machine IDs:

```
tester2      1.2.3.4     ZZZ
tester5      1.2.3.4     XYZ
tester5      1.2.3.4     OOO
tester1      6.6.6.6     BBB
```

I then proceed to look up all of the machine IDs for the user, which gives us one more alias of him (from machine ID `OOO`):

```
tester4      2.3.4.5     OOO
```

Looking up `OOO` I find yet another IP, 2.3.4.5, which gives me yet another connection:

```
tester3      2.3.4.5     ABC
```

Since we've looked up machine ID `ABC` before, there's no need to look it up again.

I've now identified all possible aliases of this user, and have a complete list of IPs, machine IDs and usernames he's used. All of this came from recursively looking up data, the results of which then had *another* recursive lookup performed on it, and so on.

My question is, how do I translate this logic to PHP/SQL?

Is there a way to extract all "connected" data straight via a query, or will some PHP processing be needed, and if so, what?

Comment: mysql doesn't do recursive queries. you can "fake" it somewhat by doing a series of self-joins, but that only works for a certain "recursion" depth, it won't keep going all the way down. it also gets extraordinarily ugly very quickly. So, yes... client-side processing is required.

Comment: I thought so. I'm just stuck on the logic of the PHP.

Comment: basically a while() loop that just keeps digging deeper and deeper until you hit the bottom (or top) of the tree.

Comment: You can also emulate a recursive query with a call to a recursive stored procedure (such as [the one proposed in this other anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3439364/1446005)) that populates a temporary table. In theory, this should be faster than making repeated queries from PHP, but it is also a bit more painful to write.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use the select query and 2 self joins on the machine id column. For example:

```
      select * from users left join users u1 on users. mid=u1.mid  left join users u2 on u1. mid=u2. mid where  name like "%tester1%"
```