# mysql select query selects any depth

Tags: mysql, facebook-fql

See the image below,say if i i/p z,i need to get o/p as x.

This is used to find parents and grand parents.

Can i do this using Mysql.

Any help in this would be appreciated.

Can this be done using facebook fql

[image: sample]

Comment: @evan:Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @Bill Karwin:I'm looking for you.I see you've answered to this type of questions.Could you look at this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `user_relationships` permissions on facebook to retrieve information about a users family.  However this requires the user to actually define people as their family members.  Here is [a link to the permissions page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/). Once you have determined which permissions you need, you can read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and learn how to implement the permission dialog into your application.

Comment: @Lix.I mean when a x send invites to y,z.Can i track it?

Comment: you can track any and all invites sent from your application... you can see who sent them and who they were sent to.

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchies are complicated in MySQL.  I don't think you can store a bunch of custom stuff in fql so you probably can't do it that way unless it's a built in feature.

Here's an article about MySQL hierarchies:
http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Managing-Hierarchical-Data-with-PHP-and-MySQL.html

See also this question with good answers:
[Hierarchical Data in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085287/hierarchical-data-in-mysql)

There are even books written on the subject:
[http://www.amazon.com/Hierarchies-Smarties-Kaufmann-Management-Systems/dp/1558609202](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558609202)

Complicated, but doable.